# MS Access: How to make a drop-down menu offer values from one table, but making it set the value of a different field when user chooses one

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, drop-down-menu, inventory

I am using MS Access 2010 to create an inventory database, and I have a form for users to enter purchase/inventory data, which looks like this:

[image]

The data underlying this form is actually stored in four separate tables - [Food items], [Invoices], [Inventory], [Food purchase data]:

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to make it so that the "invoice ID" dropdown in the form presents the user with a list of all of the invoice IDs that are currently present in the [Invoices] table. But once they select an option from that list, I want the dropdown to set the Invoice ID field in the [Food purchase data] table to that number. Basically, I'm just trying to make sure that when orderers are entering data in the [Food purchase data] field they are only able to enter/select values that are valid Invoice IDs.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding some code to the After Update event of the invoice combo box.

You should set the bound column of the Invoice combo box to be the InvoiceID. You'll need the ID of the FoodPurchase record you want to set too.

```
Dim sql as string

If Nz(<InvoiceCombo.Value>,0) <> 0 Then
    sql = "UPDATE <FoodPurchaseTable> SET <InvoiceID> = " & <InvoiceCombo.Value> & " "
    sql = sql & "WHERE <FoodPurchaseID> = " & <FoodPurchaseRecordID> & " ;"
    CurrentDB.Execute sql    
End If
```

Change the items in the <>'s to match your controls and tables. The  is the name of the field in the table and  is the index of the record you're trying to set.